# Rails, Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' on Ubuntu with unicorn and nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, unicorn

I'm trying to run my rails app on Ubuntu for the first time using nginx and unicorn. My question is, when I look at my log, I see the following error.

```
`app error: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml` (
RuntimeError)`
```

I looked at my `secrets.yml` which looks like,

```
...    
production:
      secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>

...
```

When I type `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE` on my command line to check to make sure that the key is set, I get a secret key, which seems to indicate that the key is correctly set. What is missing here?

Comment: Where is the entry of SECRET_KEY_BASE. Can you please show your bashrc ?

Comment: export SECRET_KEY_BASE="2658----------------ddd"

Comment: It's at the end of my .bashrc

Comment: did you deployed your app to VPS? Check if there is `secrets.yml` file on your app on server.

Answer (score 0):

Your unicorn process runs as root. however you probably set your key with non-root user.
To fix this problem, I recommend you to use dotenv(https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).